# Nomenclature concordance in R

Tags: r, merge

I have to do what is called a nomenclature concordance in R for categorizing product codes, which requires a right join operation from one version of product codes to a new version (through a one to many or less commonly many to one correspondence table):

```
  #Dataset:
  products<-c("030799","030789","219090")
  tradevalue<-c("150","50","75")
  df<-data.frame(products,tradevalue)
  
  #Correspondance table:
  products <- c("030799","030799","030799","030789","030789","219090")
  products.new <-c("030749","030784","030788","030783","030787","219090")
  
  #the new trade value has to be divided by the number of new generated rows
  tradevalue.new<-df$tradevalue / ???
  
  #so here it would be divided by 3, 2 and 1 for the examples above  
  tradevalue.new<-c("50","50","50","25","25","75")
    
  concord<-data.frame(products, products.new, tradevalue.new)
  
  new <-right_join(df,concord)
```

So instead of the original 3 rows in `df`, there are now 6 rows in `new`, but the total trade value for each product remains the same but is equally distributed to the new product categories in the new version, but the divisor is the number of new lines for each product.

Can you please help?

Comment: Why are you using strings as numbers and expecting math to work on them?

Comment: Hi, sorry I was just trying first to show the problem properly. Yes, it should be numeric for that one variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with numerical data,

```r
df <- structure(list(products = c("030799", "030789", "219090"), tradevalue = c(150, 50, 75)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
concord <- structure(list(products = c("030799", "030799", "030799", "030789", "030789", "219090"), products.new = c("030749", "030784", "030788", "030783", "030787", "219090"), tradevalue.new = c(50, 50, 50, 25, 25, 75)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

we can do

```r
library(dplyr)
right_join(df, concord, by = "products") %>%
  group_by(products) %>%
  mutate(tradevalue.new2 = tradevalue / n()) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 x 5
#   products tradevalue products.new tradevalue.new tradevalue.new2
#   <chr>         <dbl> <chr>                 <dbl>           <dbl>
# 1 030799          150 030749                   50              50
# 2 030799          150 030784                   50              50
# 3 030799          150 030788                   50              50
# 4 030789           50 030783                   25              25
# 5 030789           50 030787                   25              25
# 6 219090           75 219090                   75              75
```

If there is a risk that one product in `df` will be repeated, then you can pre-define a row id:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  right_join(concord, by = "products") %>%
  group_by(rn) %>%
  mutate(tradevalue.new2 = tradevalue / n()) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 6 x 6
#   products tradevalue    rn products.new tradevalue.new tradevalue.new2
#   <chr>         <dbl> <int> <chr>                 <dbl>           <dbl>
# 1 030799          150     1 030749                   50              50
# 2 030799          150     1 030784                   50              50
# 3 030799          150     1 030788                   50              50
# 4 030789           50     2 030783                   25              25
# 5 030789           50     2 030787                   25              25
# 6 219090           75     3 219090                   75              75
```

Comment: Hi I'm not too sure about this first() function, it seems to call only the very first value of all the ```tradevalue``` column values for all the calculations, rather than the first one for each new product group? The original dataset also has other columns/ data groupings such as year and reporter country, I'm not sure if this is affecting the value. What I need is to get the number of generated new product codes (grouped by product, and the country and the year) and divide the original trade value by this number. Perhaps something like ```seq_along()```?

Comment: It's not necessary, it's been removed.